# "Formula" for velocity

Tags: real-analysis, average

Let $I:=[0,L]$ and $\langle N\rangle$ be the average number each of kinks and antikinks (i.e. there are in average $N$ kinks and $N$ antikinks) in $I$. Moreover, let $\langle n\rangle=\frac{\langle N\rangle}{L}$ and $\frac{\langle m\rangle}{L}$, where $m$ is the kink density per unit length and $n$ is the antikink density per unit length.

The velocity of kink and antikink is given as $u$ and $-u$, respectively.

Now, let $\theta(x,t)$ be the displacement angle for $x\in I$ at time $t$.

Moreover, assume that each kink and antikink passing some fixed point $x$ along $I$ brings an increase of $2\pi$ in $\theta(x)$.

> > Therefore, I read, 
> >     $$
> > \langle\partial\theta / \partial t\rangle=2\pi u (\langle n\rangle + \langle m\rangle ).~~~(*)
> > $$

I have some problems to understand $(*)$. I guess that $u\langle n\rangle + u\langle m\rangle$ is the (average) number of kinks and antikinks per unit length that pass the fixed point $x$.

But how does this fit together with the units?

$\langle\partial\theta / \partial t\rangle$ should be something like the average angular velocity.

The velocity of the kinks and antikinks, $u$, hould be something like
$$
u=\frac{\Delta z}{\Delta t}
$$
where $\Delta z$ is some distance on $[0,L]$ and $\Delta t$ is some small time interval.

$\langle n\rangle$ and $\langle m\rangle$ are the average number of kinks and antikinks per uni length.

But I do not see why the right hand side of $(*)$ should give the average angular velocity.

Comment: Is there a source for this? My guess would be that this is consistent with how they've chosen units (e.g. the physics predilection for taking $c=1$ and therefore time having units of length.)

Comment: Could you explain that a bit? Its not clear for me what you mean e.g. with "time having units of length). The source is "Forced and overdamped sine-Gordon Soliton Gas" by Büttiker

Comment: Should that be "Kinematics of the force..."? Re: the units, see Wikipedia's page on [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units).

Comment: Yes, thats the whole title. sorry. messed it up.

Comment: In terms of units, I think things are fine: the kink velocity would have units of length per unit time, and the (anti)kink density would have units of inverse length, so their product would have units of inverse time i.e. frequency as is appropriate for an angular velocity. What I find strange is that the two densities are added rather than subtracted: the kink increases $\theta(x)$ by $2\pi$ whereas the anti-kink decreases it by that much. So I think I'm missing something.

Comment: I just have problems to understand the product of $u$ and the sum (or maybe difference) of the densities. As far as I see this product $u(\langle n\rangle + \langle m\rangle)$  is supposed to be the total number of the kinks and antikinks that pass $x$. But I do not see why this product IS indeeed this number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45244/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-mathfemi).